# A phrase for a tip or trick passed down from one generation to the next

Tags: phrase-requests

Many use the phrase *life hack* to describe a novel or clever solution to an everyday problem. Before this expression became popular I remember seeing another phrase in the English language to describe the same thing. It is possible that it  also refers to a secret passed down within a family.

I remember this phrase from the title of a TV programme that used to air in the UK. It had segments of homemakers using half a plastic bottle to make a funnel, or using an old dustbin to make a home for hedgehogs.

Does anyone know the phrase I'm trying to remember?

Comment: Sort of *grandmother lifehacks*?:http://lifehacker.com/whats-the-best-life-hack-your-mother-or-grandmother-tau-499873691

Comment: Most people have no clue what “life hack” is intended to mean.

Comment: "We often use...?"  WHO often use? Honestly, I've never HEARD anyone say "life hack."  I've SEEN it - in the headlines of poorly written Yahoo "helpful hints" articles... supposedly, somebody thinks it's clever.  I sincerely don't hold out much hope for "hack" replacing "hint", "tip", or "trick", in the day to day lexicon because "hack" will always conjure images of hatchets and cleavers and blood and gore.

Comment: For medicine/illnesses there were/are "*home remedies*"; though your question has sparked a vague recollection in me that there's a broader or more general term.

Comment: In the U.S. the term _makeshifts_ is often used to describe things like the improvised funnel.

Comment: @DanBron I believe "home remedies" is coming close to the phrase I was thinking of. Perhaps it contains the word "home".

Comment: [List of Britiish TV Programmes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_television_programmes)

Comment: Actually, there is a Lifehacks SE.  But I agree that it's not (at least until recently) a common term that many people would understand.

Comment: *Tricks of the trade* refers to wisdom acquired by those who have done something a lot.

Answer (score 4):

*[Folklore](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/folklore)*:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 The traditional beliefs, customs, and stories of a
>   community, passed through the generations by word of mouth.
>
> ODO

Which includes: ***Folk wisdom***, ***Folk memory***, ***Folk music***, ***Folk remedies***, ***Folk medicine***, etc.

From etymonline.com

> *[Folklore](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=folklore&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> "traditional beliefs and customs of the common people," 1846, coined
>   by antiquarian William J. Thoms (1803-1885) as an Anglo-Saxonism
>   (replacing popular antiquities) in imitation of German compounds in
>   Volk- and first published in the "Athenaeum" of Aug. 22, 1846; see
>   *[folk](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=folk&allowed_in_frame=0)* + *[lore](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lore&allowed_in_frame=0)*. Old English folclar meant "homily."
>
> This word revived folk in a modern sense of "of the common people,
>   whose culture is handed down orally," and opened up a flood of
>   compound formations: Folk art (1892), folk-hero (1874), folk-medicine
>   (1877), folk-tale (1850; Old English folctalu meant "genealogy"),
>   folk-song (1847, "a song of the people," translating German
>   Volkslied), folk-singer (1876), folk-dance (1877).
>
> *[lore](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lore&allowed_in_frame=0)*:
>
> Old English lar "learning, what is taught, knowledge, science,
>   doctrine, art of teaching," from Proto-Germanic *laizo (Old Saxon
>   lera, Old Frisian lare, Middle Dutch lere, Dutch leer, Old High German
>   lera, German Lehre "teaching, precept, doctrine"), from PIE *leis- (1)
>   "track, furrow" (see *[learn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=learn&allowed_in_frame=0)*).

A current TV program entitled *[Folklorist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2622434/)*.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the phrase I am looking for... Sorry I do not have any good information to give.

Comment: No problem, Alex. It is not the word you are looking for, but it may be the word someone else is looking for in the future. Good question!

Comment: I would add "folk wisdom".

Answer (score 0):

The recipe for *Coca Cola* is a trade secret. There is an **old family secret** that tells you to use it as a [cleaning solution](http://www.brightoncleaningcompany.co.uk/news/clean-with-coca-cola/) because it contains citric acid.

Comment: IIUC, it also contains phosphoric acid, which is more corrosive than citric acid.

Answer (score 0):

**tried-and-true / tried and true (methods)** (adj.)

> Proved good, desirable, or feasible : shown or known to be worthy
>
> *A **tried-and-true** sales technique*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tried-and-true)

> Used by many people and proved to be effective:
>
> *Most people would prefer to stick to **tried and true methods** of birth control.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/try?q=tried%20and%20true)

---

> Grandma was a woman of primitive means. She preferred to use her old
> **tried-and-true methods** of doing things—from washing, drying, ironing, and sewing out clothes to finding food for out table and how
> she prepared it.
> [Cheryl Soden Moreland; *Kokomo Kid*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AYLeAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandma%20taught&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBkJGXxYqCAxX7F1kFHVrwDzQQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandma%20taught&f=false) (2014)

> Once you've established the perimeters of your research and start
> searching for your Polish, Czech, or Slovak roots, you'll want to
> adhere to **tried-and-true methods** and concepts that apply to all
> genealogy research. Following these guidelines helps you avert
> unnecessary brick walls and trace the right ancestors.
> [Lisa Alzo;
> *The Family Tree Polish, Czech and Slovak Genealogy Guide*](https://books.google.com/books?id=twMyEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandma%20taught&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY44XMxoqCAxULMlkFHcsJDe44FBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandma%20taught&f=false) (2016)

> My **tried and true** way of cooking rice seems to turn out just right
> every times, and it is the easiest method possible. My grandfather
> taught me to cook it this way, so I don't claim any credit for its
> success, but try it for yourself.
> [Terri Wuerthner; *In a Cajun
> Kitchen*](https://books.google.com/books?id=V6yrmGVzRtAC&pg=PA17&dq=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandpa%20taught&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI0u_jx4qCAxWJF2IAHVeBDnUQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=tried%20and%20true%20method%20that%20grandpa%20taught&f=false) (2007)